# How can I close the terminal window after launching a program using ANT's <exec>?

Tags: linux, apache, ant, exec

Using Apache ANT in Linux, I need to open a program and after that close the terminal window. The terminal command is of the kind:

```
#> evince /home/my.pdf & exit
```

I'm trying the following:

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh">
   <arg value="-c"/>
   <arg value="evince /home/my.pdf &amp; exit"/>
</exec>
```

But this immediately closes the terminal and also the application.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine:

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh">
   <arg value="-c"/>
   <arg value="nohup evince /home/my.pdf &gt;&gt; /dev/null &amp; exit"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh" spawn="true">
   <arg value="-c"/>
   <arg value="nohup evince /home/my.pdf &gt;&gt; /dev/null &amp; exit"/>
</exec>
```